Is this belief about other people's beliefs paradoxical?
Is the following a paradox?
I believe that there are some people who believe in falsities.
Is what I believe true?
(if what I believe is false, then it must be true)

It is more of an orthodox.

You say "I believe that there are some people who believe in falsities". If you really believe it then it's true (that you believe it). If you don't then you are lying. I don't see a paradox.

No, I mean is what I believe true, not if the whole sentence is true.

@Adam, I am totally lost ...

I meant if what I believe is false, then there must be a person believing in a falsity, so what I believe is true. Is that clear?
